# How does Kayn's shadow-orb signal work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do you see that?

[image: Kayn's signal to warn enemies about his presence]

Whenever there's an enemy champion near the terrain Kayn's in, this orb will show up. But it's not clear where it will: I have recorded one such situation in my own game:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BHTTe_xvUD9irLMQSu0suQmKNcvP7MHQ

To cut short Riven's pursuit, I had walked into nearby terrain. The orb appeared, this time right beside her, even though I had run a long way yonder.
Does anyone have an answer to how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an indicator as to where Kayn will be pushed to/placed if his Shadowstep [E] duration runs out while he is still within impassable terrain.

If Kayn is currently within impassable terrain and gets placed into combat, the duration of Shadowstep gets lowered to 1.5 seconds (doesn't apply if Shadowsteps duration is lower than 1.5 seconds when placed into combat).

Comment: but in my recorded video, Kayn had run far away from Riven, yet the indicator appeared right beside her. How could Kayn be pushed back such a distance like that?

Comment: @RevolNoom in your video it looks like the orb wasn't well moving. Maybe it's just a visual bug, or maybe a real bug and Kayn would have been pushed back here.